# How to query for Metadata in CloudKit JS?

Tags: javascript, ios, metadata, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

**I've figured out how to query for *some* metadata for example calling this in my query:**

```
<td>" + record['created'].value + "</td> <-- populates some table data
```

But this comes back **undefined** which confuses me because the CloudKit dashboard has a value for Created By (as part of the automatic Metadata that is created with each record.)

How do I query for the ID/UUID as well as get the response in a HTML/JS-readable manner?

Comment: With Dave's help I wrote a query to get the timestamp, it looks like this: 

`<td>" + record['created'].timestamp + "</td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fetching one or more records with CloudKit.js you'll notice you get back an Object that looks like this:

```
{
    "recordName": "6E863D3D-5371-4376-A9BA-3B294F480E4E",
    "recordType": "Message",
    "fields": {
        "text": {
            "value": "hi",
            "type": "STRING"
        },
    },
    "recordChangeTag": "ib461v1s",
    "created": {
        "timestamp": 1434751588720,
        "userRecordName": "_36ed4b61e7a11c9302f851fe25a9b911",
        "deviceID": "_2"
    },
    "modified": {
        "timestamp": 1434751588720,
        "userRecordName": "_36ed4b61e7a11c9302f851fe25a9b911",
        "deviceID": "_2"
    }
}
```

The `recordName` is a record's unique identifier, and the Object has a `created` attribute which points to an Object with a `timestamp` field.